# Hot to transform self invoking <script> to native JS code?

Tags: javascript

the usual GTM code looks like this:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','myNewName','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

If formatted readable, it looks like this:

```
<script>
(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
    w[l] = w[l] || [];
    w[l].push({
        'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
    });
    var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
    j.async = true;
    j.src =
        'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
})
(window, document, 'script', 'myNewName', 'GTM-XXXX');
</script>
```

So this function is an anonymous function which will be executed automatically, right? How can I use this code in a vanilla javascript construct. So for example this code should only be executed if another variable is true.

```
if (var === true) {
execute gtm inclusion and run the code...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. It's not possible to do this without changing the `<script>` tag to a `<template>` tag (or similar) and using `eval`, which itself has it's own problems. It would be better to remove/show the script tag on the server end as it's not possible to do this from the client.

Comment: Why can't you just put the google tag manager code in a if statement?

Comment: @Dan, why can't you add the if statement after the brace in `(function (w, d, s, l, i) {` and the end brace for the if statement goes after `f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);`?

Comment: @dan it's possible dear; take a look at my answer

Comment: It's possible if you modify the HTML file on the server, which is precisely what I suggested @Leonardo. It's not possible to do this on the client, which is what OP was asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1] As @imvian2 and @Dragonsnap have mentioned above, you can also wrap the statement as such:

```js
if (runCode) {
  (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
  new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
  j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
  'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','myNewName','GTM-XXXX');
}
```

2] Another possible way to do this, is to put the gtag code in it's own js file. Then you can load it with javascript.

WARNING: It is highly likely that google/gtag expects it's code to be placed directly in-page and not loaded in such a manner, so that it can detect all page load events. You will need to be aware of this and test, test, test.

RECOMMENDATION: I would do this with backend-code, NOT with js.

```js
function addScript(scripts) {
    // IE9
    if (!Array.isArray(scripts)) scripts = [scripts];
    for(var i=0, n=scripts.length; i < n; i++) {
        var scriptElem = document.createElement('script');
        scriptElem.async = false; // load scripts in order
        scriptElem.src = scripts[i];
        // IE9
        var headElem = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        headElem.appendChild(scriptElem);
    }
}

var loadGtag = true;
if (loadGtag) {
    addScript('/path/to/my/gtag-script.js');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give a [script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) tag an **invalid** `type` attribute to tell browser skip it's parsing/execution. then later on with JavaScript correct that attribute and hint the browser to execute it; I intentionally didn't handle consecutive errors for simplicity's sake.

```js
function enabler() {
  let sc = document.querySelector("script[type='foobar']");
  sc.removeAttribute("type");
  // remounting 
  sc.parentElement.appendChild(sc);
  sc.remove();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="enabler()">enable script</button>
<script type="foobar">
  console.log("Now I am executing")
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const GTM = ((w=window, d=document, s="script", l='myNewName', i='GTM-XXXX') => {
  w[l] = w[l] || []; //.... etc.....
  console.log(i); // Just to test
});


if (/*something is*/ true) GTM();
```